# Make Eclipse point me to encoding errors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I´m changing a Java project to use UTF-8 encoding. I made the change in preferences dialog in Eclipse, so that now I see lots of weird characters in code, strings and comments.

Is there any way to make Eclipse flag those characters as errors in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse cannot reliably point you to *encoding errors*.

Consider this character sequence for example

> RÃ¼diger

which is clearly encoded in the wrong way. But without having a dictionary and knowing that this should actually be a German name, no machine can mark this an encoding error.

You need to convert all text files that are affected from the encoding change from the existing encoding to UTF-8.

Assuming that the existring encoding is ISO-8859-1 / Latin 1 you may use `iconv` like this:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 myFile.xyz > myFile.utf8abc
```

Comment: Oh well, thanks, can you recommend something like iconv for windows?

Comment: iconv has also been ported to Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm